# to extract 6th word in 4th line of text files.using CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i have tried to extract 6th word from 4th line but loop is not working can anybody tell what is the error in the syntax of commands used

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("D:\H Drive\subh\test\OUTPUT\*.*") do (
for /f "usebackq tokens=6 delims= " %%g IN ('more %%a | findstr /n $ | findstr /b "4:"') do (
set var=%%g
echo %var%
)
)
pause
```

Comment: As you have [already asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584385) before, could you please delete one or other of them.

Comment: Don't use `more` to spew text in a loop. It will stop mid stream and wait for input. Use the `type` command.

Comment: ...or use neither, in most cases `FindStr` can do it without!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `skip` option in a `for /f` loop to go directly on the right line, when the word is found we use a `goto` command to break the loop :

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.txt) do call:get6 "%%a"
echo done!!
exit/b

:get6

for /f "skip=3 tokens=6" %%b in ('type "%~1"') do (
    set "$6=%%b"
    goto:next
)
exit/b

:next
echo %$6%
```

**EDIT :**

After @stephan comment here is the same code using the original `findstr /n` method :

```
@echo off

for %%a in (*.txt) do call:get6 "%%a"
echo done!!
exit/b

:get6

for /f "tokens=6" %%b in ('type "%~1" ^| findstr /n $ ^| find "4:"') do (
    set "$6=%%b"
    goto:next
)

exit/b

:next
echo %$6%
```

Comment: Note: this gives false results if one of the first 3 lines is empty (the original `findstr /n` method will handle that)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it in a cmd.exe shell.

```
SET "FILELIST=D:yy\H Drive\subh\test\OUTPUT\*.*"

powershell -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-ChildItem -Path \"%FILELIST%\" |" ^
        "ForEach-Object {" ^
             "Get-Content -Path $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 5 -First 1 | ForEach-Object { ($_ -split '\s+')[5] }" ^
        "}"
```